# Regex to match a string only inside another string

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose here is a sample text:

```
Hello this is testing _testisgood _test test ilovetesting again test
```

The regex

```
/test/gi
```

Gives all the `test` but I only want the `test` string which is surrounded by some other character except space means the opposite of exact match. In other words the `test` in `testing` , `_testisgood` ,`ilovetesting` i want to match.

Comment: how about `_test`? it doesn't come after `whitespace`

Comment: You said you "only want the test string which is surrounded by some other character except space means the opposite of exact match." Considering that `"testing"` is a match, *surrounded* seems like the wrong word and I don't know what "opposite of exact match" means (an "inexact match"?). You need to state the problem more precisely, such as "I wish to match 'test' when it is (not preceded  by a ???) and is (not followed by a ???)" or ".... when it is (preceded  by a ???) and is (followed by a ???)".

Answer (score 2):

Bill's answer is good but may you like this one: just find all words with test and then filter out useless ones;

```
const s = "Hello this is testing _testisgood _test test ilovetesting again test"
 
console.log(
    (s.match(/[^\s]*test[^\s]*/gi) || []).filter(s => s !== 'test')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex below will match `'test'` when it either has a non-whitespace character(s) prefixing or post fixing it.

`/([^\s]+test[^\s]*|[^\s]*test[^\s]+)/gi;`

**OR**

`/(\S+test\S*|\S*test\S+)/gi;`

```js
const sentence = "Hello this is testing _testisgood _test test ilovetesting again test";

regex = /([^\s]+test[^\s]*|[^\s]*test[^\s]+)/gi;

console.log(sentence.match(regex));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match just `_testisgood` and `ilovetesting` in your example by specifying one or more characters that are **not** whitespace before and after `test`, like this:

`/[^\s]+test[^\s]+/gi`

If you also want to match `testing`, then drop `[^\s]+` from the beginning of the pattern.

Comment: It is not detecting `test` in `testing`

Comment: @s_guha96 See my update.

Comment: I have modified this `[^\s]+test[^\s]+|[^\s]+test|test[^\s]+` if it have not whitespace on either sie then take it

Answer (score 0):

should still work like this `\btest\w+|\w+test\b|\w+test\B\w+`

Comment: It would help if you explained what this does

Answer (score 0):

Since a "word" in your scenario is a chunk of one or more non-whitespace chars (and a non-whitespace char is matched with `\S` in regex) you can use

```js
console.log(
  "Hello this is testing _testisgood _test test ilovetesting again test"
    .match(/\S+test\S*|\S*test\S+/gi))
// => ["testing","_testisgood", "_test", "ilovetesting"]
```

Here, `\S+test\S*|\S*test\S+` (see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AxNXWq/1)) matches either

- `\S+test\S*` - one or more non-whitespace chars, `test` and zero or more non-whitespace chars
- `|` - or
- `\S*test\S+` - zero or more non-whitespace chars, `test` and one or more non-whitespace chars.

Or, you can split with any one or more whitespace chars (with `.split(/\s+/)`) and then filter out any chunk that is equal to `test` string or does not contain `test` string:

```js
console.log(
  "Hello this is testing _testisgood _test test ilovetesting again test".split(/\s+/)
    .filter(x => x.toLowerCase() != "test" && x.toLowerCase().includes("test")))
```

**Considering your expected output** it may seem that you want to match any non-whitespace chunk that contains `test` and at least one more letter. In that case, you can use

```js
console.log(
  "Hello this is testing _testisgood _test test ilovetesting again test"
    .match(/[^\sa-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]\S*test\S*|\S*test[^\sa-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]\S*/gi))
// => ["testing","_testisgood", "_test", "ilovetesting"]
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AxNXWq/2). Output: **`["testing", "_testisgood", "ilovetesting"]`**

*Details*:

- `[^\sa-zA-Z]*` - any zero or more chars other than whitespace and letters
- `[a-zA-Z]` - a letter
- `\S*test\S*` - `test` enclosed with zero or more non-whitespace chars
- `|` - or
- `\S*test[^\sa-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace chars, `test`, any zero or more chars other than whitespace and letters and then a letter and zero or more non-whitespace chars.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is:

> Gives all the test but I only want the test string which is surrounded
> by some other character

Let's do it with another approach string *built-in functions*, instead of *`Regex`*

```js
function surroundedBy(string, wordInMiddle){
  const allWords = s.split(/\s+/);
  const wordsSurrounded = allWords.filter(word=>word.toLowerCase().includes(wordInMiddle) && 
                                                        !word.startsWith(wordInMiddle) && 
                                                        !word.endsWith(wordInMiddle))
  return wordsSurrounded;
}
```

***Test:***

```js
const s = "Hello this is testing _testisgood _test test ilovetesting again test"
console.log(surroundedBy(s,'test'))
```

**Result:** `['_testisgood', 'ilovetesting']`